# Key/value pairs pylance issue

Tags: pylance

After typing the following script: my_posts = [{"title": "title of post 1", "content": "content of post 1", "id": 1},
{"favorite foods",  "content": "I like pizza", "id": 2}]

**Key/value pairs are not allowed within a set Pylance** is the error message I am receiving with "I like pizza" and 2.

Here are the libraries I have imported:
from typing import Optional
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.params import Body
from pydantic import BaseModel

I would appreciate any insight regarding this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The first entry in your second dictionary (`"favorite_foods"`) is just a string, not a key value pair. This makes pylance (and python for that mattet) treat it as a set, not a dictionary, which is why you’re getting the error you’re getting. I'm guessing you meant `"title": "favorite_foods"`.

Comment: Thank you for your advice.  I typed everything out verbatim as demonstrated in the tutorial.  Everything was kosher on his screen.

Comment: Even in tutorials, people make mistakes ;) He'd have noticed had he tried to run the code.